# Angular 4 eqvalent of ng-disabled

Tags: html, angular

I have two ckeckboxes and one is disabled when the second one is clicked. I have done it in angularjs but couldn't do the same thing on angular 5 project?

```
<li>
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="notWorking" ng-model="body.NotWorkShift" ng-disabled="body.All"/>
        <label translate >Notworkshift</label>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class=" checkbox-inline ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="allCars"  ng-model="body.All"  />
        <label translate>AllCars</label>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<input type="checkbox" class="notWorking" ng-model="body.NotWorkShift" ng-disabled="body.All"/>
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" class="notWorking" ng-model="body.NotWorkShift" [disabled]="body.All"/>
```

Comment: I have tried the same approach and also with [(ngModel)] but i just couldn't make it work

Comment: ohhh it worked now i needed to define the other inputs as standalone.like this , [(ngModel)]="body.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}